# Ruby on Rails Tutorial Chapter 6.3.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org

When I create user account, I get this warning.
What does this message mean?

> ```
> SyntaxError: /Users/KOSUKE/workspace/score_share/app/models/user.rb:6: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end
>    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }
>           ^
> /Users/KOSUKE/workspace/score_share/app/models/user.rb:7: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end
>    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
>               ^
>     from /Users/KOSUKE/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:457:in `load'
>     from /Users/KOSUKE/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:457:in `block in load_file'
>     from /Users/KOSUKE/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:647:in `new_constants_in'
>     from /Users/KOSUKE/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:456:in `load_file'
>     from /Users/KOSUKE/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:354:in `require_or_load'
>     from /Users/KOSUKE/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:494:in `load_missing_constant'
>     from /Users/KOSUKE/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `const_missing'
>     from (irb):1
>     from /Users/KOSUKE/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
>     from /Users/KOSUKE/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
>     from /Users/KOSUKE/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
>     from /Users/KOSUKE/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
>     from /Users/KOSUKE/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
>     from /Users/KOSUKE/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
>     from /Users/KOSUKE/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
>     from /Users/KOSUKE/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
>     from /Users/KOSUKE/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
>     from /Users/KOSUKE/workspace/score_share/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
>     from /Users/KOSUKE/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
>     from /Users/KOSUKE/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
>     from /Users/KOSUKE/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
>     from /Users/KOSUKE/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
>     from /Users/KOSUKE/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
>     from /Users/KOSUKE/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
>     from -e:1:in `<main>'2.2.1 :002 >
> ```

Comment: Could you post the full `user.rb` file here?

Comment: The likely error is that you have omitted the `,` from the `validates` directive in your model; you need `validates :param, uniqueness: { x: y}, presence: true` (notice the commas)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your **user.rb** file looks *exactly* like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  has_secure_password
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you that your `user.rb` has an syntax error:

```
SyntaxError: /app/models/user.rb:6: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end
format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }
      ^
/app/models/user.rb:7: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end
uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
```

You are probably just missed a `,` or a closing `}`.

Revisit your `user.rb` (especially line 5-7) and double check that it looks exactly like the [example in the book](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/modeling_users#_code-password_implementation).